# jQuery Validator - Validator fails silently after errorPlacement is added

Tags: jquery, validation

I've checked this in firebug on Chrome and FF.  No errors are reported and nothing is logged to the console.

UPDATE: Plugin is working but my placement of errors is making them invisible.

<s>If I remove the errorPlacement Validator starts working again.  What am I missing?</s>

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#surveyForm").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
            if ( element.is(":radio") ) 
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() ); 
            else if ( element.is(":checkbox") ) 
                error.appendTo ( element.next() ); 
            else 
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next() ); 
        }                     
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get it working using your javascript and the HTML found at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation - is there any chance you can post the HTML form?

Comment: I'd have to create a new dummy copy from rendered HTML- live copy is a private form.  Will try to post copy now.

Comment: While doing that I discovered the problem seems to be that I am actually making all of the labels inaccessible.  The plugin seems to be functioning.